# Unit test: assert exception-handling function called

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a custom exception handler function which allows printing error message instead of raising exception where required. I would like to assert it is called in edge cases.

`with pytest.raises(Exception)` works as intended if I raise exception within the exception handler. In the case of printing `pytest.raises` would fail assertion.

I tried patching the exception handler and asserting that it was called but the assertion failed, saying it was not called.

```
def the_function(sth):
    try:
        do something with sth
    except Exception:
        exception_handler("err_msg", print=False)

def exception_handler(err_msg, print=False):
    if print is True:
        raise exception
    print(err_msg)

# in testcase file
class Test_the_function(unittest.TestCase):
        @patch('exception_handler_resides_here.exception_handler')
        def test_function_calls_exception_handler(self, mock):
            the_function(sth_bad)
            self.assertTrue(mock.called)
```

I tested the syntax worked for asserting if a function was called within another function.

Any help on how I should approach this would be appreciated.

> Edit:
>   To clarify, I'm trying to test the performance of the_function, not whether exception_handler can be called

Comment: You need something like `@patch('yourmodule.exception_handler')` instead.

Comment: I did specified the module in my code. Added that in now :)

Comment: There is a big difference between `@patch('foo')` and `@patch(foo)`. The quotes in my original comment are intentional.

Comment: Very terrible of me. Yes I have that in my code too but forgot to add here because I don't understand why it's done like that. Thanks

Comment: `foo` is an identifier that refers to an object in the *current* scope; `'foo'` (as `patch` uses it) is the name of the identifer used in a *different* scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Chepner is right

This statement is correct.

self.assertTrue(mock.called)

`mock.called` does return True/False

This shows how mock works.

```
import mock
mocked = mock.Mock()
mocked.methods.called
False
mocked.methods()
<Mock name='mock.methods()' id='139652693478928'>
mocked.methods.called
True
```

Here is to test the_function by patch the exception_handler.

```
import unittest
import mock
def handler_side_effect(sth):
    exception_handler("err_msg", to_print=True)


def the_function(sth):
    try:
        sth.pop()
    except Exception:
        exception_handler("err_msg", to_print=False)


def exception_handler(err_msg, to_print=False):
    if to_print is True:
        raise Exception('aaa')
    print(err_msg)


class Test_the_function(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('python2_unittests.test_called.exception_handler')
    def test_the_function(self, mocked_handler):
        # no exception
        the_function([1])
        self.assertFalse(mocked_handler.called)

        # with exception, but will not be raised
        the_function(None)
        self.assertTrue(mocked_handler.called)

        # force to trigger a raise Exception
        mocked_handler.side_effect = handler_side_effect
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            the_function(None)
```

Comment: The purpose of `self.assertTrue` is to raise an exception, marking the test as failed, if `mock.called` evaluates to `False`. Simply evaluating `mock.called` as a no-op expression statement doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Calling `mock.assert_called()`, on the other hand, would accomplish roughly the same thing as using `self.assertTrue(mock.called)`.

Comment: @chepner, you are right, `the_function` should be patched to throws an exception instead of having to force an exception in my example. There is nothing wrong with the `self.assertTrue(mocked_handler.called)`

Comment: If I patch the_function and give it a side effect, that would test exception_handler but not the_function itself, which is not my intention. Sorry for confusion. Edited the question to add clarity now.